# Tune radio with laptop

Tags: rf, computers

I want to sintonize (tune) local FM and AM radio stations with my laptop. I know nothing about electronics and thought this was the place to put my question, I don't know any site more relevant to this. What hardware and software do I need?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by 'sintonize'? It's not a term I've ever heard, nor something I can find a definition for.

Comment: @magmastonealex yes "sintonizar" means "to tune" in spanish, and I thought it was the same in english. Now it's fixed.

Comment: It's not possible to listen to FM or AM broadcasts with a laptop, you need very specific components. Making a simple receiver is very easy - just search Google "FM Receiver" (or AM).

Comment: There are usb radio tuners for your computer. Check eBay and various sites.

Comment: Thank you all for your responses guys. The best for the community is to close the question.

Comment: Although I agree this question is no longer on topic (since you don't need to build anything), I answered it anyway and provided a bunch of links for Software Defined Radios (SDR) because now I want to get one.  :)

Comment: I have seen "syntony" in an English language book where it referred to tuning different stations at different frequencies. The book was published in 1903 and the author was of the opinion that this was impossible and Marconi was finally off his rocker. (The book also predicted that submarines would traverse the sea floor on wheels, that Professor Langley would soon achieve manned powered flight, and that automobiles were about to end the problem of pollution in major cities. A wonderful book...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can buy the front end of a multiband radio or transceiver (transmit & receive) in a USB dongle, and the rest of the work is done inside the laptop as a [Software Defined Radio](http://gqrx.dk/) (SDR).

Here is a list of [compatible hardware](http://gqrx.dk/supported-hardware) for this particular software (Gqrx, built on top of GNU Radio)..

[This one](http://www.adafruit.com/products/1497), for only $22.50, can tune FM radio stations but not AM.

[image]

Many of these allow you to transmit as well, but for that in general you would need an FCC ham radio license, unless you were transmitting at very low power (like 100 milliwatts on FM, check regulations before doing so).

Here's a screen capture of the Jawbreaker SDR (one of the more expensive dongles, it covers 30 MHz to 6 GHz) visualizing and tuning the FM radio spectrum:

[image]